# Indexing info via DataImportHandler without credentials

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler, dih

Does anybody know how dih is indexing info without credentials? To save doc via HttpSolrServer I have to use credentials, but saving via dih there is no need to use it. Why? Can I save additional info by customizing dataimporthandler library?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure I answered this exact question a couple of days ago, but DataImportHandler lives inside your Solr instance. When DIH runs, it is part of the regular Solr process - it doesn't make any queries through the regular HTTP API of Solr, and thus, doesn't require authentication (which is a pretty recent option in Solr as well).

You can create your own DataImportHandler implementations, or write your own RequestHandler if needed - or if you need more processing when adding a document, extend the DIH with a scripttransformer or add an update chain.